# Spring MVC - Page Not Found

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, web

So here's my project :

WebConfig.java :

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
}

public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {

    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new         InternalResourceViewResolver();
    //strings to views
    //success from a controller -* prefix/success/suffix
    //success from a controller -* /WEB-INF/pages/success.jsp
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

    return resolver;
}
}
```

AppInitializer.java :

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.register(WebConfig.class);

    container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

    DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(rootContext);

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = container.addServlet("dispatcherServlet", dispatcherServlet);
    registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    registration.addMapping("/");
}

}
```

**P.S :** my "index.jsp" page is in : /WEB-INF/pages/

And I'm still not getting the index page : it says it's not found.
*Thanks for your help.*

Comment: Why do you think you should _get the index page_? What part of your application configuration here do you think serves it? Why do you think so?

Comment: Well, I followed a tutorial and the man did get his page, I was wondering why me !! And I already mapped the default "/" to "index" so I don't see the problem here..

Comment: Can you link to the tutorial? What do you think your `internalResourceViewResolver()` method is meant to do?

Comment: [link](https://www.udemy.com/java-spring-mvc-framework-with-java-based-configuration/). And I thought that method should search and direct to the views, NO ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add @Bean annotation to that resolver and @ComponentScan(basePackages = "yourPackages") to the configuration class

Try to get overtype of resolver:

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver()
{
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

    return viewResolver;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! but can I you explain what it does exactly (I mean the method)

Comment: It set view resolver, configured by Java annotations. View resolver is responsible in spring for resolving views by name. For example if you got mapping method in controller and that mapping returning string, that resolver is responsible for search in our views page with that name.

Comment: and last question : why do we need to set it as a bean ?

Comment: @Bean is used to explicitly declare a single bean, rather than letting Spring do it automatically as above. It decouples the declaration of the bean from the class definition, and lets you create and configure beans exactly how you choose. Spring get that bean from the context when he need it. He knows that he is waiting for some action in container:)